# Send a List<Interface> as WCF method parameter

Tags: c#, wcf

How can I send a generic list of the type of an interface to a WCF method? the problem I have is that the client generated the list as `List<object>` instead of using the interface.

Comment: It might be useful to post your Data/Service/Operation contracts

Comment: Is that interface available in the client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's probably because the client doesn't know what implementations exist for this interface as they are not part of the exposed metadata. You could use [known types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) to include those possible implementation in the WSDL.

Comment: Where should I place the knowtype attribute? Should I create a class that implements my interface and define is a datacontract and the apply the knowtypeattribute with the interface type? and should I leave my parameter as List<Interface>?

Comment: @ryudice, there are many possibilities, all covered by the article on MSDN I linked to. Personally I do this in web.config as it is the least obtrusive way.